# What could be the reason for these HTTP IOExceptions?

Tags: java, http

I'm using Java code like this to execute queries on a certain site:

```
String query( String query ){
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient(); 
        URI uri = ...;
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri( uri )
            .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response;
        try {
            reqCounter++;
            response = client.send( request, BodyHandlers.ofString() );
            return response.body();
        } catch (IOException ioe ) {
            System.err.print( ioe.getMessage() );
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        } 
}
```

After some very successful requests, one right after the other, to the same site, an IOException is thrown, showing a message of

- "null", after a varying number of requests, perhaps 50 or 150 (only since a couple of days)
- "no route to host", always after more than 900 requests, hardly ever more than 1000. I can restart after a long coffee break, maybe 10 to 15 minutes, and all goes well Till The Next Goodbye.
- "GOAWAY", after a varying number of requests, less than 100, typically after a hasty restart after the last termination due to the previous reason.

Sleeps of 0.1 s to 0.3 s before each request don't help, and also long sleeps (10*60 s) after 900 requests don't avoid the IOException.

I have been complaining ~7 days ago to the maintainers of the site. They deny any complicity in this.

Has anybody ever seen anything like this, and what would be the best strategy to get several thousand requests without constant manual intervention?

Comment: Does closing the client/request or reusing the client help?

Comment: "no route to host" curiously sounds like rate limiting kicking in and issuing a network block (e.g. fail2ban and friends).

Comment: I suggest that you add `ioe.printStackTrace()` to the `catch (IOException ioe)` block. The entire stack trace may provide details that may help you determine the cause of the problem. And if not, it may help you to debug the code by showing you the best place to add a breakpoint.

Comment: @MrTux No: a program restart after less than ~10 mins will run into "no route" or "GOAWAY" after a small number of requests.

Comment: @dhke I was thinking along these lines, too. That site had a very simple identification scheme with an additional query parameter until March this year. - I'll read the fail2ban doc and see how it may match my experience. Do you know one of the "friends"?

Comment: @Abra Do you suggest I should debug Java's libraries?